# Bash: Looping urls using curl, giving only first url output

Tags: bash, shell, url, curl

**What I want to do**: I want to find all the products(URLs) which are not redirected.

To get the final URL after redirection I'm using `curl` command as follows:

`curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "$URL"`

This is working fine. Now I want to iterate over URLs to get which are the URLs that are not redirected and display them as output of program. I've the following code:

```
result=""
productIds=$1
for productId in $(echo $productIds | sed "s/,/ /g")
do
    echo "Checking product: $productId";
    URL="http://localhost/?go=$productId";
    updatedURL=`curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "$URL"`

    echo "URL : $URL, UpdatedUrl: $updatedURL";
    if [ "$URL" == "$updatedURL" ]
    then
            result="$result$productId,";
    fi
done
```

The curl command works only for the first product. But from 2nd to last product, all the `URL` and `updatedURL` are same. I can't understand the reason why? The `productId` is changing in every iteration, so I think it cannot be something related to caching.

Also, I've tried the following variant of `curl` also:

`updatedURL=$(curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "$URL")`

`updatedURL="$(curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "$URL")"`

---

Edit: After trying with debug mode and lot of different ways. I noticed a pattern i.e. If I manually hit the following on terminal:

`curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "http://localhost/?go=32123"`

Then in shell script these urls will work fine. But if I don't hit manually then `curl` will also not work for those products via shell script.

Comment: How are you invoking the script, i.e. what is `$1`/`$productIds`?

Comment: `sh test.sh 123,456,789,221` is what I'm using to invoke the shell script. `$1` is what I'm using to get user input inside script.

Comment: put `#!/bin/bash -vx` in the top line and make test.sh executable and then call test.sh without sh - should give lots of debug output so you can see if the URL assignment works

Comment: can you detail "curl will also not work via shell script", what exactly happens? can you try 
`curl -L "$URL"

echo $?
updatedURL=\`curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "$URL"\``
inside the loop to see what is so strange about these calls?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `#!/bin/bash` to be the first line of shell. It does produce required output. Now invocation should be like this **bash file.sh  123,456,789,221**
[image: shell and its output]

Invocation via Bourne shell **sh file.sh 123,456,789,221** does requires code changes.Do let me know if you require that too :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your loop to something like this:

```
IFS=, read -ra productIds <<<"$1"
for productId in "${productIds[@]}"; do
    url=http://localhost/?go=$productId
    num_redirects=$(curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{num_redirects} "$url")
    if [ "$num_redirects" -eq 0 ]; then
        printf 'productId %s has no redirects\n' "$productId"
    fi
done
```

This splits the first argument passed to the script into an array, using a comma as the delimiter. The number of redirects is stored to a variable. When the number is zero, the message is printed.

I have to admit that I can't see anything inherently broken with your original approach so it's possible that there is something extra going on that we're not aware of. If you could provide a reproducible test case then we would be able to help you more effectively.

Comment: This loop doesn't helped. Same problem. It is doing the same thing as the previous one. Also, you might want to change `product_ids` in your read line to `productIds`.

Comment: Good point about the variable name, I forgot to change them both back after testing (I normally use underscores in shell scripts). I would still suggest this approach as it saves you using an external tool. Unfortunately I can't really debug without knowing what your variables are. I'd suggest using `set -x`.